# Angular $location get empty object with Expressjs

Tags: angularjs, express

Recently I have do some search in Angular,In my project, I need to use it which is to export data to excel file.Here is my flow:

```
Get querystirng -> send to express -> output file
```

service module:

```
factory('getExcel', function($http,$location,$route){          
        return {
            getData: function(callback){
                var queryString = $location.search();
                console.log('queryString',queryString);  //empty object
                console.log('route', $route.current.params)  //empty object
                return $http({
                    method:'GET',
                    url: '/Excel',
                    params:{
                      ...  // This will send to express,but I got nothing
                    }
                }).success(callback);
            }
        }
    });
```

Controller module:

```
controller('someCtrl', function(getExcel){
   $scope.exportExcel = function(){
      ....
      getExcel.getData() 
      ....
   }

});
```

Express:

```
app.get('/Excel', function(req, res) {
    //wait for data
    console.log(req.query);
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: show your routing on angularjs side

Answer (score 0):

I soloved it. becasuse I passed before the $location.search() change the URL.